# Adding KafkaConnect to existing Ambari services

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a cluster setup and managed by Ambari however I would like to add a KafkaConnect docker and utilise Kafka and ZooKeeper which is already setup through Ambari. I am only able to find docker images which deploy kafka-connect with both zookeper and kafka however I am not in need of these on the docker.

What should I be looking into, to find a docker image which lets me use existing kafka and zookeeper services?

Comment: Ambari won't manage Docker services or Kafka Connect.

Comment: I am not looking for Ambari to manage anything. I just want to deploy a docker image with Kafka Connect that uses Kafka and Zookeeper which is installed through Ambari

Comment: I'll try again. Docker is not managed by nor can containers be installed by Ambari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Kafka 0.10 is installed by Ambari (as done by Hortonworks HDP or HDF), then Kafka Connect is already included in the Kafka installation.

Ambari does not presently offer any mechanism for managing Docker images/services or Kafka Connect APIs.

Flume, Spark, and Nifi are the supported, Ambari managed ways by Hortonworks to get Kafka data into Hadoop.

If you want a Kafka Connect UI, your options include Landoop (free) or Confluent Control Center (licensed)

You can independently use services like Docker Swarm + Portainer, for example, for managing Docker services on many machines

Comment: Perfect. that's the answer I am looking for! if I do a `find | grep kafka-connect` I cannot see anything. I do have kafka version `kafka_2.10-0.10.1.2.6.2.0-205.`

Comment: It's not "installed" as an individual package. You should be able to find `connect-distributed.sh` under `/usr/hdp/current/kafka`

Comment: Ah yes, there it is. Thanks heaps :)